# Fast scala compiler unable to compile mutable TreeMap

Tags: scala

```
object Test {

var returnData: scala.collection.mutable.TreeMap[Char, Char] =  scala.collection.mutable.TreeMap[Char, Char]()
}
```

If i compile this class with fsc(using scala 2.12.1) then it gives me an error :

```
object TreeMap is not a member of package scala.collection.mutable
var returnData: scala.collection.mutable.TreeMap[Char, Char] = scala.collection.mutable.TreeMap[Char, Char]()
```

But if i compile the same with scalac then it gets compiled successfully.

Comment: do you mean compiler-server ?

Comment: Well... `scala.collection.mutable.TreeMap` was added in Scala 2.12. It was not there in Scala 2.11.x

Comment: In other words, kill the 2.11 with fsc -shutdown, then restart with 2.12. Just running `scala` script runner will kick off the daemon.

Answer (score 0):

Works just fine with Scala 2.12.1

```
$ scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.12.1 -- Copyright 2002-2016, LAMP/EPFL and Lightbend, Inc.


$ cat > script.scala
object Test {

var returnData: scala.collection.mutable.TreeMap[Char, Char] =  scala.collection.mutable.TreeMap[Char, Char]()
}

$ fsc script.scala
$ ls
script.scala  Test.class  'Test$.class'
```

You must be having your setup mixed up with Scala 2.11.x.